# How can i derive this using StateSpaceModel?

Tags: differential-equations, control-systems

Please how can I solve this using StateSpaceModel.

```
eqns := {(lp \[Theta]''[t]) + m g Sin [\[Theta][t]] + c \[Theta]'[t] -
  Sin [\[Theta][t]] y0''[t] == 0};
```

Comment: Do you mean put it in a state space form?

Comment: Yes, I need to put it in  a state space form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`StateSpaceModel`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StateSpaceModel.html) is a linear representation. It will throw away nonlinear terms.

```
eqns = {lp θ''[t] + m g Sin[θ[t]] + c θ'[t] - Sin[θ[t]] y0''[t] == 0};
StateSpaceModel[eqns, {θ[t], y0[t]}, {}, {θ[t], y0[t]}, t]
```

> [image]

[`NonlinearStateSpaceModel`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NonlinearStateSpaceModel.html) can handle nonlinear terms, but it doesn't support descriptor systems yet. For now, we have to use an internal function as shown [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/212512/5998).

```
{{f, h, e}, x} = Control`DEqns`nonaffinestatespaceForm[eqns, {{θ[t], 0}, {y0[t], 0}}, 
    {}, {θ[t], y0[t]}, t, #[[1 ;; 2]] &, DescriptorStateSpace -> True];
```

The state space equations are in the form $e.x'==f$.

```
x
```

> [image]

```
{e.D[x, t], Table["==", 4], f}//Transpose // TableForm
```

> [image]

Comment: Thanks you very much.